# Name for rational connection between irrational numbers

Tags: terminology, irrational-numbers

I'm trying to find the established name, if there is one, for what I'll call "rational connection" in this post.

So we would say some irrational number $x$ is "rationally connected" to another irrational number $y$ if $$x=a\times y^b + c$$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are rational numbers

For example:

The sum of the reciprocal of the squares is the irrational number $1.6449...$, and this number is "rationally connected" to $\pi$, as it can be represented in the form $a\pi^b + c$ where $a$, $b$ and $c$ are rational numbers, specifically $\frac{1}{6} \pi^2 + 0$.

One example of two irrational numbers that aren't "rationally connected" are $e$ and $\pi$.

Comment: Can you prove your last claim?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_independence for a more general concept

Comment: Surprisingly, whether $e$ and $\pi$ are rationally connected is an open problem.

Comment: More concretely, we don't even know whether $\pi+e$ is itself rational—!

Comment: To the OP: this notion of "rationally connected" isn't completely natural, because it's not symmetric in the two numbers. For example, according to this definition, $\pi^2+1$ is rationally connected to $\pi$, but $\pi$ is not rationally connected to $\pi^2+1$.

Comment: @GregMartin that's true, it should be $x = (a * y^b + c)^d$ maybe? Or wouldn't it work either?